# How can I add attendees to a single event instance programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, events, calendar, instance

I am trying to add a group of attendees to an recurring event in Google Calendar. However, I want to add one attendee from the group to a single event instance.

Does each event have their own id, or are they only distinguishable by a combination of event_id and begin and end?

The instanceIdList only contains the event_id, and they are all the same. Do I have to combine the event_id with ex. Instance.BEGIN to add attendees to ONE single event instance?

```
    int countOuter = 0;
    int countInner = 0;
    int numberOfAttendees = selectedNames.size()-1;      //selectedNames: the chosen attendees

    // If only one attendee is chosen
    if(selectedNames.size() == 1)
    {
        ContentValues attendees = new ContentValues();
            attendees.put(Attendees.ATTENDEE_EMAIL, emailList.get(selectedNames.get(0)));
            attendees.put(Attendees.EVENT_ID, eventID);
        Uri uriAttendees = resolver.insert(Attendees.CONTENT_URI, attendees);
            uriAttendees.buildUpon();
    }
    else
    {
        if(!instanceIdList.isEmpty())
        {
            while(instanceIdList.size() > countOuter)
            {       
                ContentValues attendees = new ContentValues();

                // Add one attendee from list to one instance of an event
                while(countInner < 1)
                {
                    attendees.put(Attendees.EVENT_ID, instanceIdList.get(countOuter));
                    attendees.put(Attendees.ATTENDEE_EMAIL,emailList.get(selectedNames.get(numberOfAttendees)));

                    countInner++;
                    numberOfAttendees--;

                    // If all attendees in list has been assigned and 
                    // there are still more instances, start assigning to 
                    // the attendees in the list again
                    if(numberOfAttendees == -1)
                    {
                        numberOfAttendees = selectedNames.size()-1;
                    }
                }
                countInner = 0;
                countOuter++;
                Uri uriAttendees = resolver.insert(Attendees.CONTENT_URI, attendees);
                uriAttendees.buildUpon();
            }
        }
    }
}

// Populating instanceIdList
// startTime is now and ends is a year from now

    String[] EVENT_PROJECTION = new String[] 
    {
        Instances.TITLE,
        Instances.BEGIN,
        Instances.END,
        Instances.EVENT_ID,
    };


    cur = Instances.query(resolver, EVENT_PROJECTION, startTime, ends);

    // Use the cursor to step through the returned records
    while (cur.moveToNext()) 
    {
        eventTitle = cur.getString(PROJECTION_EVENT_TITLE);
        eventStartDt = cur.getLong(PROJECTION_EVENT_START);
        eventEndDt = cur.getLong(PROJECTION_EVENT_END);
        instanceID = cur.getLong(PROJECTION_EVENT_ID);

        if(eventTitle.equals(taskName))
        {
            instanceIdList.add(instanceID);
            iids.add(instanceID);
            instanceStart.add(eventStartDt);
            instanceEnd.add(eventEndDt);
        }
```

Comment: row_id and event_id seems to be the same

Comment: You will have to combine multiple rows. How are you populating instanceIdList?

Comment: I added the population of instanceIdList at the bottom. Btw, I made a mistake, row_id and event_id was not the same - I forgot to add correct index.

Comment: Why are you using cur.getLong() to a String variable and not using Long.valueOf() or some other cast method?

Comment: What do you mean by recurring event? What is the periodicity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, and according to [the official `Attendees` table contract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Attendees.html), you cannot add different `Attendees` to different `Instances` of the same recurring `Event`, because you can only associate an event_id to an `Attendee`, not an "instance_id"(which does not exist).

Once you assign one `Attendee` to a recurring `Event`, all the `Instances` of that `Event` will have your `Attendee` assigned.

In alternative, you may have to create multiple `Events` with the same hourly dates and with the same periodicity of your `Instances`, so you could add different `Attendees` to each of those different event ids.

Comment: I agree. Seems like it is no way around that you have to insert the event_id when adding attendees. However, it is strange because it is possible when you add an attendee to a recurring event on Google Calendar website.

I will try to create individual event instead as you mentioned. Thanks.